# Getting a Select Value after appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

This is for javascript and jquery.

I have in my body...

```
    <select id="option1_select" name="courseCodeSelectName">
        <option></option>                       
        <option>Word1</option>
        <option>Word2</option>
    </select>   
    <script>
        $("select").change(function () { 
            functionLoadOpt2() }).trigger("change" );
    </script>

    <select id="option2_select" name="courseNumSelectName">
        <option></option>
    </select>
   <button onclick="changePage()">Load Textbook Page!</button>
```

As we see above, the web page has 2 select boxes and a button. Depending on what you select in the first select box loads what is in the second one, using the functionLoadOpt2 function locating higher up in my code.

```
if (result == "Word1") {        
     $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter1</option>');
```

...
There is more but it follows the same code different values.

Result is the following, above the if statement(just a row up),

```
var result = (document.getElementById('option1_select').value);
```

now on the button click, the function changePage() runs,
and all I want is ...

```
var result = (document.getElementById('option1_select').value);
var result2= (document.getElementById('option2_select').value);
```

Assume they selected and option for both. Result2 doesnt work. I'd imagine because I'm appending it but how would I work around this. So that when I click changePage() I get the selected value of option1_select and option2_select.

functionLoadOpt2:

```
function functionLoadOpt2(){

    var opt1Val = (document.getElementById('option1_select').value);


    $("#option2_select").find('option').remove().end().append('<option></option>');

    if (opt1Val == "Word1") {

        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter1</option>');
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter2</option>');
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter3</option>');
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter4</option>');
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter5</option>');
    }else if (opt1Val == "Word2") {

        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter3</option>');//they have similar ones in some cases
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter6</option>');
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter7</option>');
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter8</option>');
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter9</option>');
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter10</option>');
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter11</option>');
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter12</option>');
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter13</option>');
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter14</option>');
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter15</option>');
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter16</option>');
        $("#option2_select").append('<option>Letter17</option>');

//this works

    }       


}
```

Comment: Can you add code for `functionLoadOpt2()` function here.

Comment: both the select fields have the same id

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery to get and set the value of `<select>` with `.val()`

Comment: this should be comment..!

Comment: I feel it answered OP question

Answer (score 0):

Both your select elements have the same id, fix it the it should be fine

```
<select id="option1_select" name="courseCodeSelectName">
    <option></option>
    <option>Word1</option>
    <option>Word2</option>
</select>
<select id="option2_select" name="courseNumSelectName">
    <option></option>
</select>
<button onclick="changePage()">Load Textbook Page!</button>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/89uDb/)

Note: You can improve the script a lot by using proper jQuery constructs, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/89uDb/2/)

Comment: @Keith check out the attached fiddle